# Html tags inside strings.xml is not working with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

While trying to define the text color in strings file like below it is working fine using java

```
<string name="price_value">Rp %1$s &lt;font color=\"#f8011e\">(-%2$s)&lt;/font> </string>
```

and the above string is getting used like this in my java code:

```
Html.fromHtml(String.format(
              getString(R.string.price_value),
              price,
              discount + "%"
            ));
```

But the same string is not working with Kotlin. Below is the code for Kotlin

```
Html.fromHtml(String.format(
              getString(R.string.price_value),
              price,
              discount + "%"
            ))
```

This string was supposed to change the color of 2nd dynamic parameter but it's only working in java but Kotlin it's not changing the color.

So can someone please tell that why is it not working with **Kotlin**?

I asked the same question on Kotlin Discussion page also, but did not get any answer there.

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/html-tags-inside-strings-xml-is-not-working-with-kotlin/7739

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure 100% sure this is what you wanted. But this will make the second parameter red.

```
var tekst = Html.fromHtml(String.format(
                getString(R.string.price_value),
                100,
                ""+10 + "%"
        ))

        tv_textview.text = tekst
```

Above results in the tekst: "Rp 100 (-10%)" with (-10%) in red.

Comment: My question is not about like how to do that thing, It's about why Html tags in not working with Kotlin.